# jquery click doesn't work on ajax generated content

Tags: jquery, ajax, click, live

I am using `$(".button").on("click", function(){ });`

to click to a button which is on a container but then an ajax call is done and the content 
gets updated with new stuff and then when i try to click `.button` it wont work... nothing will get returned when i click the button.

I even tried

```
$(".button").live("click", function(){ });
```

or

```
$(".button").click(function(){ });
```

How can I make it work?

**EDIT :**
my html:

```
<div class="container">
   <ul>
       <li>item1</li>
       <li>item2</li>
       <li>item3</li>
   </ul>
   <input type="button" value="reload" class="button" />
</div>
```

Comment: Please show What is being returned by the ajax call.

Comment: And the rest of jQuery that attaches the listener. What you're describing is exactly what `live` is supposed to handle, so it's strange that that isn't working.

Comment: i have a ul where i click on them and simply echo "test" in javascript with .on("click") but when i click the button it will do an ajax call and reload the ul but then it will stop doing nothing when i click the button.. it wont return anything.

Answer (score 162, accepted):

Should be done this way.

```
$('body').on('click', '.button', function (){
        alert('click!');
    });
```

If you have a container that doesn't change during the ajax request, this is more performant:

```
$('.container').on('click', '.button', function (){
        alert('click!');
    });
```

Always bind the delegate event to the closest static element that will contain the dynamic elements.

Comment: Thanks for the answers! Still think this is very weird and doesn't feel allright to use this way. Wish jquery had a better way of handling these kind of situations

Comment: @MiguelStevens, read [on's docs](http://api.jquery.com/on) once you read and understood the concept, it won't be weird and will make perfectly sense.

Comment: But how would I write parent for this... $("input#someId").autocomplete({//some code});...there is no on event here..

Comment: @Sadaquat, I suggest writing a full question with all the required details in a different thread. If you won't get an answer, you can ping me with a comment and I'll try my best to help.

Comment: i did the same but its not working..any suggestions?

Comment: Finally I found the solution I was looking for! Thank you sir

Answer (score 41):

Ok i solved my problem by using the .on() function correctly since i was missing one parameter.

instead of

```
$(".button").on("click", function() { } );
```

i used

```
$(".container").on("click", ".button", function() { } );
```

Comment: Just a note, the [selector argument is not required](http://jsfiddle.net/62uSU/3/), but is necessary in this case.

Comment: Why is the selector argument not required, but necessary in this case?

Comment: I think it's because the selector is re-run in this case, but if not included it is not captured in the originally-run list of items grabbed with the selector.

Comment: @stergosz thanks man it really solved my tension.

Answer (score 8):

Instead of:

```
$(".button").on("click", function() { } );
```

I used:

```
$(".container").on("click", ".button", function() { } );
```

I have used this and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

Is this what you're trying to do? Note, I'm putting the `$.on()` on the parent, but selecting the `.button` for the action.

> .on( events **[, selector]** [, data], handler(eventObject) )
>
> **selector** A selector string to filter the descendants of the selected
>   elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null or omitted,
>   the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
<div id="stuff">
    <button class="button">Click me!</button>
    <p>Stuff</p>
</div>

var $stuff = $('#stuff'),
    ajaxContent = $stuff.html();

$stuff.on('click', '.button', function(){
    $.get('/echo/html/', function(){
        $stuff.empty();
        console.log($stuff.html());
        alert($stuff.html()); // Look behind, #stuff is empty.
        $stuff.html(ajaxContent);
        console.log($stuff.html());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/62uSU/1

Another demonstration:

```
var $stuff = $('#stuff'),
    ajaxContent = $stuff.html(),
    $ajaxContent,
    colors = ['blue','green','red'],
    color = 0;

$stuff.on('click', '.button', function(){
    $.get('/echo/html/', function(){
        color++;
        if (color == colors.length) color = 0;
        console.log($stuff.html());
        alert($stuff.html());
        $ajaxContent = $(ajaxContent);
        $stuff.append($ajaxContent).css('color', colors[color]);
        console.log($stuff.html());
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/62uSU/2/