# How to open page in a new tab in browser?

Tags: javascript

I'm executing the following script in Google Chrome:

```
window.open('form.xhtml', '_blank');
```

However, it opens the page in a new window instead of a new tab. How can I open it in a new tab?

Comment: you might want to take a look at here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999837/force-window-open-to-create-new-tab-in-chrome

Comment: I tryed but didn´t find a solution, it works well on `Firefox` or `Internet Explorer`

Answer (score 0):

you can see the blog 'http://www.cnblogs.com/xiyangbaixue/p/3959954.html',as you did, window.open(,'_blank') will open a new window, you should remove the param of '_blank'

Comment: Ok, but how can I redirect to this JSF page? If I am in a `list.xhtml` and need to open in the new tab `form.xhtml`? Using `action` method?