# Chrome window.open("page.html", "Target") opens in locked down chrome window

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, window.open

Let me preface this by saying, this is for an enterprise application. So don't worry about the usual client side limitations and issues of a normal website.
Been racking my head for days to no avail. So I'm resorting to here in hopes someone can solve this.

What I need to do:
Launch a url in chrome that always loads in the same chrome browser window.
This can be done from command line or from another chrome window(preferably JS, but I am open to ideas)

The issue:
An inbuilt security feature in chrome (works fine in IE) prevents javascript from launching full fledged new windows without user interaction to initiate it. What you get instead is a locked down window that ignores the target window you are trying to launch to.
By locked down window, I mean no toolbar, can't edit the url, and it ignores the target parameter.
No error is thrown.

Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120 m

[image: Locked down window]

None of the command line options I tried work, maybe I missed one that would fix it though.

Here is the PoC code that works in IE but not Chrome:
html launched via command line in chrome:

```
<HTML>
    <BODY>
        <SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
            var win = window.open("landing.html", "CustomTarget");
            window.close();
        </SCRIPT>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

I'm very good a JavaScript, but very little in stuff like jQuery. I am open to using them, just please explain them well. Any help is greatly appreciated. All the best!

Comment: I'm confused about your question.  you have an application on the user's computer in IE and you want to cause a page to load inside their Chrome instance?

Comment: You can not open a window because of the pop up blocker in the browser.

Comment: @epascarello It is not a popup blocker. It is a chrome security feature that locks down new windows launched without user action.

Comment: @lukevp We already accomplish that through browsium. Additionally we need the application launched in chrome to reused it's window. The code I posted works in IE. We need to do exactly that in chrome. But chrome has an inbuilt security feature that locks down new windows that are launched without user action. 
Maybe too much info there, I will simplify it.

Comment: Any screenshots or error messages from the "chrome security feature"? If any, please update the question accordingly.

Comment: @Kenji " It is a chrome security feature that locks down new windows launched without user action." That sounds like the definition of a pop up blocker.

Comment: @cychoi No... it just gives you a locked down window instead of a normal one.

Comment: @epascarello Again, this is a corporate enterprise environment, we do not have any pop up blockers installed, and the chrome popup blocking option is disabled. The window opens, it is just locked down.

Comment: What is a "locked down window"? How does it look like? If we can't understand what you mean by words, why not take a screenshot or even a screencast? Anything refraining you from doing that?

Comment: @Kenji currently it seems you can't have toolbar, editable urlbar, etc for Chrome and there would not be any workarounds. What are you exactly trying to do? Why do you need to use `window.open()`? Probably there would be other solutions for your purposes. See the relevant information from the web: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999837/force-window-open-to-create-new-tab-in-chrome
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15818892/chrome-javascript-window-open-in-new-tab
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=82522