# open multiple tabs on user event in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, underscore.js

I want to open multiple tabs in chrome to let user download multiple documents (not .zip) The have done codin using underscore.js. I am using window.open() in _.each() method. but chrome does not open more than one tab.Please help.

Comment: There are good answers to this question. Try Bagelzones  [Chrome explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16749907/window-open-behaviour-in-chrome-tabs-windows) and maclema's answer on [using callbacks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11999837/force-window-open-to-create-new-tab-in-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

When I needed to open URLs in new tabs, I used [@Amro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11389138) modified as appears here:

```
// From https://stackoverflow.com/a/11389138
function openNewBackgroundTab(url) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = url;
    var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    //the tenth parameter of initMouseEvent sets ctrl key
    evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
                                true, false, false, false, 0, null);
    a.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```